# Reducer's not being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, immutability

I'm trying to update a property of an object that is nested in an array of my reducer state. The reducer receives the good payload but does not my view does not get updated.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
//reducers.js

case UPDATE_ROOM_TMP: {
  const roomIndex = state.config.rooms.findIndex(room => room.id === action.payload.id);
  return { 
    ...state, 
    rooms: state.config.rooms.map(
      (room, i) => i === roomIndex ? { ...room, tmp : action.payload.tmp} : room
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the structure of the reducer state:

```
config: {
  ...
  rooms: [
    {
      ...,
      tmp: 22
    }
  ]
}
```

The action to update the reducer:

```
export const updateRoomTmp = ({ targetTmp, roomId }) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ROOM_TMP,
    payload: { targetTmp, roomId },
  };
};
```

The function that calls the action:

```
  increaseTmp = () => {
    const tmp = this.props.config.rooms[this.roomIndex].targetTmp + 1
    this.props.updateRoomTmp({targetTmp: tmp, roomId: this.props.room.id});
  }
```

The Text that presents the new value

```
  <Text>{this.props.config.rooms[this.roomIndex].targetTmp}</Text>
```

How I connect to config:

```
const mapStateToProp = ({ allConfig }, props) => {
  const { config } = allConfig;
  return { config };
 };
```

So the problem is that when increaseTmp is called, the reducer receives the good payload but never get updated, so the text does not get updated either.

Comment: This type of issue can often be solved with a couple of console logs. In your reducer, log what you are about to return from the function. In `mapStateToProps`, log the state. Use `JSON.stringify()` or `util.inspect()` to show you the entire content of those two objects. This will tell you if your reducer shape matches the expected state shape.

Comment: I've done many console.logs, I don't see any problem, Actually if there was a shape matching problem I would've got an error. That's why I can't spot the problem

Comment: Hmm, well one of two things is true. 1) The props being received by your component are incorrect. 2) The state being received by mapStateToProps is not what you expect. If you don't have problem (2), but you do have problem (1), then either your mapStateToProps isn't working right (doesn't pull out the right data from state), or it isn't being called/isn't connected to the component. Console logging `this.props` at the top of your `render` method will tell you when you get new props and what they are. Console logging `mapStateToProps` will tell you when it is being called.

Comment: One easy mistake to make (which I do all the time) is to forget to use the connected container component and instead import the view component. But in that case mapStateToProps would never be called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `reducers.js` like,

```
case UPDATE_ROOM_TMP: {
const roomIndex = state.config.rooms.findIndex(room => room.id ===action.payload.id);
    return { 
            ...state, 
            config:{
            ...config,
            rooms: state.config.rooms.map( (room, i) => i === roomIndex ? { ...room, tmp : action.payload.tmp} : room)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting config is not defined tryna figure out why